# Algebra/Number Theory Problem regarding primes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find the smallest $n$ in which $4n^4 -2017n^2 + 4 = p^3q$ in which $p$ and $q$ are primes.

I tried modding $4$ to the whole expression and got to $pq$ is congruent to $3$ mod $4$. However, I couldn't get an answer from that. It is also factorable into $(2n^2+45n+2)(2n^2-45n+2)$. However, I couldn't get much from that either.

Comment: You can do the same thing with $3$ to find $n^4 + 2n^2 + 1 \equiv pq \mod 3$, unless $p$ is $3$

Comment: Which one is a square in $2n^2\pm 45n + 2$ ?

Comment: Does $n$ have to be positive? Could you use, e.g., $n = -23$, for which $p = 5$ and $q = 419$? I found this with a routine search in WolframAlpha ([**link**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2n%5E2+%2B+45n+%2B+2+%3D+m%5E2+and+2n%5E2+-+45n+%2B+2+%3D+mk)).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman obviously the sign of $n$ is unimportant; it only appears in even powers.

Comment: @Joffan Yes, I suppose a moment of reflection indicates as much.

Answer (score 1):

You already have
$$(2n^2+45n+2)(2n^2-45n+2)=p^3q$$
Since there are no integers $n$ such that $2n^2+45n+2\lt 0$ and $2n^2-45n+2\lt 0$, there are four cases to consider :
$$(2n^2+45n+2,2n^2-45n+2)=(p^3q,1),(p^2q,p),(p^2,pq),(p^3,q)$$
(Replacing $n$ with $-n$ corresponds to the other cases : $(2n^2+45n+2,2n^2-45n+2)=(1,p^3q),(p,p^2q),(pq,p^2),(q,p^3)$.)

Case 1 : $(2n^2+45n+2,2n^2-45n+2)=(p^3q,1)$

There are no integers $n$ such that $2n^2-45n+2=1$.

Case 2 : $(2n^2+45n+2,2n^2-45n+2)=(p^2q,p)$ 
$$(q=)\ \frac{2n^2+45n+2}{(2n^2-45n+2)^2}\ge 2\iff 8n^4-360n^3+4064n^2-405n+6\le 0\tag1$$
Let $f(n)$ be the LHS of $(1)$.

- If $n\le 0$, then $f(n)\gt 0$.
- If $1\le n\le 10$, then $f(n)=n(8n^3+360n(10-n)+59n+405(n-1))+6\gt 0$
- If $n\ge 29$, then $f(n)=n(2n\left(2 n - 45\right)^2+14(n-29)+1)+6\gt 0$.

Checking if $f(n)\le 0$ for $11\le n\le 28$ gives 
$$(1)\iff n=22,23$$ However, $2\times 22^2-45\times 22+2=-20,2\times 23^2-45\times 23+2=5^2$ are not primes.

Case 3 : $(2n^2+45n+2,2n^2-45n+2)=(p^2,pq)$

We have$$p\mid (2n^2+45n+2)-(2n^2-45n+2)=90n$$

So, there exists an integer $k$ such that $90n=kp\iff n=\frac{kp}{90}$ from which we have
$$p^2=2\left(\frac{kp}{90}\right)^2+45\cdot\frac{kp}{90}+2\iff 8100=p(4050p-k^2p-2025k)$$
So, $$p\mid 8100=2^2\times 3^4\times 5^2\implies p=2,3,5$$
There are no integers such that $2n^2+45n+2=2^2,3^2$ and 
$$2n^2+45n+2=5^2\implies n=-23\rightarrow 2\cdot (-23)^2-45\cdot (-23)+2=2095=5\times 419$$ where $419$ is a prime.

Case 4 : $(2n^2+45n+2,2n^2-45n+2)=(p^3,q)$

We have
$$2n^2+45n+2=p^3\iff (4n+45)^2=(2p)^3+2009$$
which has no integer solutions according to [Numbers n such that Mordell's equation y^2 = x^3 + n has no integral solutions](https://oeis.org/A054504).

Therefore, the answer is $\color{red}{n=-23}$. (If $n$ is a positive integer, then the answer is $n=23$.)

Answer (score 0):

$n=23$ is the smallest such $n$ which give two prime $p=5,q=419$.

A brute force is sufficient to show that.